# Is it possible to store arrays in one variable and use Explode on them later?

Tags: php, arrays

If I want to store different strings in one variable I can do this:

```
$everything = $something.';'.some.';'.data1;
```

And if I want to have it back in the same structure I can do in that way:

```
$everything = explode (';', $everything);
$something = $everything[0];
$some = $everything[1];
$data1 = $everything[2];
```

**And the question is:** Is this possible to store an array values in the same way like mentioned above and use `explode` on them later?

```
$everything = $array1[].';'.somearray[].';'.data_array1[];
$everything = explode (';', $everything);
$array1[] = $everything[0];
```

Or it can be done in more easly that I don't know yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to serialize and unserialize the whole deal, like so:

```
$everything = serialize(array($array1, $somearray, $data_array1));
list($array1, $somearray, $data_array1) = unserialize($everything);
```

That said, I don't see why would you like to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

> Generates a storable representation of a value
>
> This is useful for storing or passing PHP values around without losing
>   their type and structure.
>
> To make the serialized string into a PHP value again, use
>   unserialize().

Answer (score 0):

you can use **implode**() function to make string . and later on you can covert it back in to array by using **explode**().

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. 
But you can store your arrays in one big array like this

```
$everything=Array();
$everything[]=$array1;
$everything[]=$array2;
$everything[]=$array3;
```

now you can access your `$array2` by calling `$everything[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the serialize and the unserialize to do this instead of joining the string yourself.

Cos based on your example. you will not be able to handle values with semicolons in them.

The serialize function will escape all these nicely for you so you do not need to care about them.

Answer (score 0):

To further these answers slightly, a good option here would perhaps be to construct a class which implements \Serializable and populate it with these values which I assume (as you're packing them together) are in some way related to one another.

This way you can encapsulate this behaviour and data in a sensible fashion and facilitate easy re-use throughout your code.

Hope this helps.